# Rails has_many :through scoped with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, associations, has-many-through

I'm trying to create a `has_many :through` association with a custom scope. The problem is that the scope has a `joins` with a 3rd model, and that seems to be breaking the association.
These are the models:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lesson_applications, through: :lesson_requests
  has_many :lessons, through: :lesson_applications
  has_many :scoped_lessons, -> { custom_scope }, through: :lesson_applications, source: :lesson
  has_many :tutors, through: :scoped_lessons # Broken association
end

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson_application
  has_one :tutor, through: :lesson_application
  has_one :time_range, as: :time_rangeable

  scope :custom_scope, (lambda {
    joins(:time_range).where('time_ranges.attribute BETWEEN ? AND ?', value1, value2)
  })
end

class LessonApplication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson_request
  belongs_to :tutor
  has_one :lesson
end

class Tutor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lesson_applications
  has_many :lessons, through: lesson_applications
end

class TimeRange < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :time_rangeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I expected to get the student's tutors from the scoped lessons, but instead I get an `missing FROM-clause entry for table 'time_ranges'`. Which is clearly and error that can be seen on the generated query.

The generated query when I do `student.tutors` is:

```
SELECT "tutors".* FROM "tutors" INNER JOIN "lesson_applications" ON "tutors"."id" = "lesson_applications"."tutor_id" INNER JOIN "lessons" ON "lesson_applications"."id" = "lessons"."lesson_application_id" INNER JOIN "lesson_applications" "lesson_applications_tutors" ON "lessons"."lesson_application_id" = "lesson_applications_tutors"."id" INNER JOIN "lesson_requests" ON "lesson_applications_tutors"."lesson_request_id" = "lesson_requests"."id" WHERE "lesson_requests"."student_id" = $1 AND (time_ranges.start BETWEEN '2018-04-11 20:27:34.798992' AND '2018-04-11 20:27:34.799090') LIMIT $2
```

The method I'm using temporarily instead of the association is:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  def tutors
    scoped_lessons.map(&:tutor).uniq
  end
end
```

I am using ruby 2.5.1 with Rails 5.1.6

Thank you in advance.

Edit: some associations were wrong.

Comment: You can't set a scope when defining an association that applies to a completely different table. There is just no way that that is going to work.  I don't really understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish - if you want to create a many to many association where a lesson has multiple tutors doing different time slots then just use LessonApplication as a join table and put the time range on that table.

Comment: But I think you really need to get back to the drawing table on your DB design as there are a lot of things that just don't work here. For example a Student `has_many :lesson_applications` but there is no corresponding `belongs_to :student` on `LessonApplication` and since the association between tutor and lesson is 1-1 there is no point in joining it on LessonApplication.

Comment: @max Sorry, I messed up copying part of my models here. I just updated the question.

Comment: I think it's a bug and was fixed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29413). Try upgrade your rails from 5.1.5 to 5.1.6

Comment: @khiavreoy I'm having the same issue with rails 5.1.6